# Create custom Annotation as alias for Framework-Annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

is it possible to create a custom Alias-Annotation to be used instead of

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused") // EventBus
public void onEvent(SomeMessage msg) { ... }
```

like

```
@EventBusListener
public void onEvent(SomeMessage msg) { ... }
```

This would be more self-documenting and should include the SuppressWarnings of course...
Sorry if this trivial but my googling failed me so far.

Comment: probably not... you have to type the whole thing:)  or use some IDE shortcut

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to write an annotation processor that transforms the AST (the compiler's internal representation of the source code).  At each occurrence of `@EventBusListener`, your annotation processor would insert an occurrence of `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`.  Later phases of the compiler would see the annotation.

Annotation processors do not ordinarily change the source code, so this takes a bit of work.  The AST is supplied to the annotation processor as an interface type, so your annotation processor would need to cast this to a concrete class and perform side effects on the concrete class.  [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) is an example of annotation processing that modifies the AST during compilation.

You might just want to write the `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` annotation, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it following way :

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public @interface EventBusListener{
    @AliasFor(annotation = SuppressWarnings.class, attribute = "value") String[] value() default {"unused"};
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Could you please explain how this works (if it does at all) and if/where this is documented?

Comment: Please note as well that `@AliasFor` is an annotation from the Spring framework.