# Reuse customized annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I use annotation @Pattern (regexp = PHONE_REGEXP, message = "{constraints.phoneIncorrectFormat}") in many places. Is it possible to save this annotation as, for example, @PhomePattern and use it? Or maybe there is another approach to reuse the customized annotation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create custom Annotation as alias for Framework-Annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813493/create-custom-annotation-as-alias-for-framework-annotation)

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is NO for standard Java.
But there is some framework support `meta-annotation`, like `spring-boot`, `jackson`.